# How to apply conditional logic to a column sorted by another column within each group

Tags: python-polars, nodejs-polars

Given the data frame

```js
const df = new DataFrame({
  group: ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
  ts: [
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:01"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:06"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:11"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:16"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:21"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:26"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:31"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:36"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:41"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:46"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:51"),
    new Date("2022-06-08T00:00:56")],
  value: [0, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 7,]
})
```

I need to apply conditional logic to a column sorted by another column within each group like below

```js
const df2 = df.groupBy("group").agg(
  col("value").sortBy("ts")
    // TypeError: col(...).sortBy(...).when is not a function
    .when(col("value").diff(1).gtEq(0))
    .then(col("value").diff(1))
    .otherwise(col("value"))
    .cumSum().alias("valueCounter")
)
```

How to calculate the `cumSum()` on the `value` column sorted by the `ts` column with previously applied conditional logic through `when/then/otherwise` to normalize counter resets within each `group`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Polars > `0.13.50` (Python)

We can combine the `diff`, `when/then/otherwise`, and `over` in the same context.

```py
(
    df
    .sort(["ts"])
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("value").diff(1) >= 0)
        .then(pl.col("value").diff(1))
        .otherwise(pl.col("value"))
        .cumsum()
        .over("group")
        .alias("valueCounter")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ group ┆ ts                  ┆ value ┆ valueCounter │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64          │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 0     ┆ 0            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 2     ┆ 2            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     ┆ 3            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 6     ┆ 6            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 2     ┆ 8            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 4     ┆ 10           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:31 ┆ 7     ┆ 7            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:36 ┆ 9     ┆ 9            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:41 ┆ 3     ┆ 12           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:46 ┆ 4     ┆ 13           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:51 ┆ 6     ┆ 15           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:56 ┆ 7     ┆ 16           │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

##### For polars <= `0.13.50` (Python)

We can use the [`partition_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html) feature to partition our dataset into a list of DataFrames, one DataFrame for each group.  We perform our calculations on each DataFrame and then concatenate the results into a single DataFrame.

```py
pl.concat(
    [
        sub_df
        .sort(["ts"])
        .with_columns(
            pl.when(pl.col("value").diff(1) >= 0)
            .then(pl.col("value").diff(1))
            .otherwise(pl.col("value"))
            .cumsum()
            .alias("valueCounter")
        )
        for sub_df in df.partition_by(groups=["group"])
    ]
)
```

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ group ┆ ts                  ┆ value ┆ valueCounter │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64          │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 0     ┆ 0            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 2     ┆ 2            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     ┆ 3            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 6     ┆ 6            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 2     ┆ 8            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 4     ┆ 10           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:31 ┆ 7     ┆ 7            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:36 ┆ 9     ┆ 9            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:41 ┆ 3     ┆ 12           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:46 ┆ 4     ┆ 13           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:51 ┆ 6     ┆ 15           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:56 ┆ 7     ┆ 16           │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

You can use the `maintain_order=True` option on the `partition_by` to keep the groups in the same order as your input if you need, but it does come with a performance penalty.

##### Edit

> The proposed solution first sorts and then groups via over(). The requirement is first group then sort within each group. Does the over() maintains previously sorted order within each group?

Yes, the `over` windowing expression will maintain the previously sorted order within each group.  Indeed, `over` will also maintain the ordering of the entire DataFrame itself.

For example, let's change our starting DataFrame, so that the timestamps within each group are identical (so that they overlap).  We'll choose the timestamps so that the observations maintain the relative ordering within each group as above, so that the result in the `valueCounter` field should be the same as the results above.  And we'll order the DataFrame so that the observations in the groups are intermingled.

We'll also add a row number so that we can see the effects of the `over` on the ordering of the DataFrame.

```py
df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "group": ["a", "b"] * 6,
            "ts": [
                "2022-06-08T00:00:01",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:01",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:06",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:06",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:11",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:11",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:16",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:16",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:21",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:21",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:26",
                "2022-06-08T00:00:26",
            ],
            "value": [0, 7, 2, 9, 3, 3, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 7, ],
        }
    )
    .with_column(pl.col("ts").str.strptime(pl.Datetime))
    .with_row_count()
)
df
```

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌────────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ group ┆ ts                  ┆ value │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 9     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 7     │
└────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

I've purposely constructed the above DataFrame so that it is already sorted only by `ts` (and not by `group` and `ts`).  That way, we do not need to sort, and can focus on the effects of `over` on the order.

Now, I'll comment out the `sort` and run the algorithm.

```py
result = (
    df
    # .sort(["ts"])
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("value").diff(1) >= 0)
        .then(pl.col("value").diff(1))
        .otherwise(pl.col("value"))
        .cumsum()
        .over("group")
        .alias("valueCounter")
    )
)
result
```

```
>>> result
shape: (12, 5)
┌────────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ group ┆ ts                  ┆ value ┆ valueCounter │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ u32    ┆ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 0     ┆ 0            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 7     ┆ 7            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 2     ┆ 2            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 9     ┆ 9            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     ┆ 3            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     ┆ 12           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 6     ┆ 6            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 4     ┆ 13           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 2     ┆ 8            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 6     ┆ 15           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 4     ┆ 10           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 7     ┆ 16           │
└────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

You'll notice that the `over` expression has not changed the ordering of the DataFrame (and thus has also maintained the ordering of the observations within each group).

Now, let's sort the result by `group` and `ts`, so that we can more easily compare the results here with the results above.

```py
result.sort(['group','ts'])
```

```
shape: (12, 5)
┌────────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ group ┆ ts                  ┆ value ┆ valueCounter │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ u32    ┆ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 0     ┆ 0            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 2     ┆ 2            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     ┆ 3            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 6     ┆ 6            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 2     ┆ 8            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ a     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 4     ┆ 10           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:01 ┆ 7     ┆ 7            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:06 ┆ 9     ┆ 9            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:11 ┆ 3     ┆ 12           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:16 ┆ 4     ┆ 13           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:21 ┆ 6     ┆ 15           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ b     ┆ 2022-06-08 00:00:26 ┆ 7     ┆ 16           │
└────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

We see that the results in `valueCounter` are the same as the results above.

We could have started our algorithm by sorting our DataFrame by both `group` and `ts`, but it is not strictly needed.  We simply need to order the observations within each group the way we need them.  The `over` expression will maintain the relative ordering within each group as it runs the algorithm.

In general, I avoid sorting a DataFrame more than is strictly necessary.  As DataFrames get large, it becomes costly to sort.

Comment: The proposed solution first sorts and then groups via `over()`. The requirement is first group then sort within each group. Does the `over()` maintains previously sorted order within each group?

Comment: Excellent question.  I've edited the answer to include a section to address your question.